# Cannot implicitly convert type error in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem with my generic method:

```
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> GetReadOnlyObjectsFromDB<T>() 
    {
        var typeofT = typeof(T);
        if (typeofT.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
        {
            return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Customer>
                  (new ObservableCollection<Customer>(dbContext.Customers));
        }
        else if(typeofT.GetType() == typeof(Article))
        {
            return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Article>
                  (new ObservableCollection<Article>(dbContext.Articles));
        }
    }
```

I always get this error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Customer>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>'`

and the same for Article. I think its clear what I want with this method but I don't know whats my mistake is...

Thanks for help and happy new year!

Comment: `Customer` and `Article` are both classes?

Comment: I see it's not a static method, in what class you're putting it ?

Comment: Hey Max, yes they are classes.

Comment: @GrayFox Max will know your comment with "@Max" just a note

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but `typeofT` will be an instance of `Type`, don't call `GetType()` on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, your method isn't generic, and you're not trying to make it generic. Don't hard-code for every possible `T`, write code that doesn't care what that `T` is. In this case, assuming you're using Entity Framework, it would look like

```
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> GetReadOnlyObjectsFromDB<T>()
    where T : class
{
    return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>(dbContext.Set<T>().Local);
}
```

Other ORMs may have similar functions. Let the `dbContext` worry about mapping `T` to the right collection, that's not something you should be worrying about.

Also, `new ObservableCollection<T>(o)` copies `o`'s items to a new list, it doesn't track any changes in `o`. Luckily, Entity Framework already provides an `ObservableCollection<T>`, that does report changes to the entities, that you can use instead.

You do need to state that `T` must be a reference type, for the simple reason that `dbContext.Set<T>` requires `T` to be a reference type.

Comment: Hey, if I try your approach, I get this error: The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: @GrayFox You're missing `where T : class`. I'd initially missed that, but have already added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're taking is not a good practice, but in order to convince the compiler to do what you want you need to cast your result items to T instead of trying to do it the other way around:

```
if (typeofT.GetType() == typeof(Customer))
    return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
              (new ObservableCollection<T>(dbContext.Customers.Cast<T>()));
```

Comment: thank you, now I understand my mistake. But I have decided to use hvd's approach.